# Git for windows not opening after update

Tags: git, heroku, git-bash, heroku-toolbelt

I've recently installed Heroku Toolbelt which had git package for windows

> **git for windows version 2.6.3**

I had an older version of gitbash which got uninstalled automatically when installing ***Heroku Toolbelt with git***.

But after installation, the new git cli for windows is not opening properly. As I try to open git, it terminates without any error within a second. I don't know what is causing the application to terminate automatically. I even tried after restarting pc but the problem still the same.

Answer (score 1):

try install Heroku Toolbelt with costume option un-checking git and reinstall git

Comment: I've already uninstalled the git that was updated with heroku-toolbelt, downloaded git again and installed it. Now its working fine for me.. Thanks for the feedback..